# Has anyone had trouble with entity framework drawing the relationship lines between entities way down on the diagram?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I'm wondering why I have relationship lines between my entities that are going 3-5 times the height of the diagram, off the bottom of the diagram, way out of the area were the entities?

When I look at the diagram it does not look as though the numbers of the points are greatly different

I'm using EF 6.1 with VS 2013 update 4 but this has been going on for a while now.  I remember it happening with VS 2012 as well